# how can i compare class to a string in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add toggle star functionality in my project. For which I'm calling this script on click. This code fails to compare value of `starclass` to the class defined in the string.
Here i m trying to add star/unstar functionality just like gmail messages to my project.

```
$(".mailbox-star").click(function (e) {
  debugger;
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this).find("a > i");
  var glyph = $this.hasClass("glyphicon");
  var fa = $this.hasClass("fa");
  var msgId = $("#MsgId").val();
  var StarClass = $(".mailbox-star i").attr('class'); 
  var StarStatus;

  if (StarClass === "fa text-yellow fa-star-o") {
    StarStatus = true;
  } else {
    StarStatus = false;
  }

  //var starstatus = document.getElementById('ReadstatusStarred');
  if (glyph) {
    $this.toggleClass("glyphicon-star");
    $this.toggleClass("glyphicon-star-empty");
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Starred",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      ChangeStarredStatus: StarStatus,
      ChangeMessageId: msgId
    },
    success: function (status) {
      if (status) {
        alert(status);
        if (fa) {
          $this.toggleClass("fa-star");
          $this.toggleClass("fa-star-o");
        }
      }
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("starfailed1");
    }
  })
});
```

//HTML CODE
here i m fetching values from my controller using model .If I can send value of IsStarred parameter in my js code my problem will be sorted

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                            <tbody>
                                @{int count = 0;}

                                @foreach (var item in Model)
{

    string[] dt = @item.DateTime.ToString().Split(' ');

    <tr title="@item.DateTime" id="ReadMessage" class="@((item.IsRead != true) ? "row row-highlight" : "row")" >
        <td><input type="hidden" value="@item.IsRead" id="Readstatus_@count"></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" value="@item.IsStarred" id="ReadstatusStarred"></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" id="MsgId" value="@item.MessageId" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td class="mailbox-star" ><a href="#"><i class="@((item.IsStarred==true)? "fa fa-star text-yellow":"fa text-yelow fa-star-o")"></i></a></td>
        <td class="mailbox-name" id="Text1" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Read", "Home", new
                                                           {
                                                               NameRead = item.FullName,
                                                               SubjectRead = item.Subject,
                                                               BodyRead = item.Body,
                                                               DateRead = item.DateTime,
                                                               MessageIdRead= item.MessageId,

                                                           })'">
            <a href="#" id="Name">
                @item.FullName
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="mailbox-subject" id="Text1">

            <b>@item.Subject</b>-
            @if (item.Body == null || item.Body.Length == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {

                if (item.Body.Length >= 100)
                {
                    @item.Body.Substring(0, 100)
                }
                else
                {
                    @item.Body
                }

            }
        </td>

        <td class="mailbox-attachment"></td>
        <td class="mailbox-date">
            @dt[0]

        </td>


    </tr>
            count++;


}


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Please post your html part too

Comment: If you `console.log(StarClass)` what do you get? Comparing classes like this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jQuery's `is()` to check for classes instead

```
var StarStatus = $(".mailbox-star i").is('.fa, .text-yellow, .fa-star-o')
```

Comment: thanks..now the if condition is working but success property of ajax method is not responding can you plz check

Comment: You can drop `.fa`. I know the TS has it, but a '.fa-*' icon always has a '.fa', so it's a double check

Answer (score 0):

If I got your description right you wanna have something like gmail has, click to star a mail, click again to destar it?

It's hard to say what is broken without the HTML you are using but I would do this in the following manner:

1. When loading mails from back you have to set up class "starMarked" to starred mails depending on how you mark the starred mail in the data comming from back you would check if something is true or equal to some value and then **.addClass("starMarked")** to that element.
2. bind the **.click(Function that does the logic below)** to all elements that represent mail (list member, square, icon, depends on what you have in the UI)
3. A functionality of that click then checks if that mail is stared or not. Since the status is already represented with class no need to check through data pulled from the server or make an additional request to the server to get that email's status. This saves time and load on the server. 
   *NOTE:* You must be certain the request to change status on the server went through or your logic of toggling on front and status on backend might become inconsistent!
4. Toggle on front could be done numerous ways but simplest would be using the CSS class "starMarked" to represent it's starred and lack of it to signal it's not. It gives 2 birds with one stone (looks and logic). If you need to check the status you could use **.hasClass("starMarked")**.

When toggling a class use **.removeClass()** to remove the class from the element